# How do I combine data from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

While creating a local movie database, I have 3 tables with below structure:

```
TABLE1: movies
movie_id | movie_title

TABLE2: categories
category_id | category_title

TABLE3: categories_movies
id | movie_id | category id
```

1 movie can have multiple categories, I'm trying to display each movie with its categories, example:

```
MOVIE TITLE 1 (Category 1, Category 2, Category 3)
MOVIE TITLE 2 (Category 2, Category 3)
```

Currently I do with 3 queries, first I select all movies:

```
select * from movies
```

Then

```
select * from categories_movies where movie_id = $movie_id
```

Then

```
select * from categories where category_id = $category_id
```

I've tested with some inner join, but no good idea, since 1 movie can have multiple categories.

Any suggestion will help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't fully understand what is the format you want to display it, but you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` if you want to display it as 1 column:

```
SELECT m.movie_title,GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_title)
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN categories_movies cm 
 ON m.movie_id = cm.movie_id
INNER JOIN categories c
 ON cm.category_id = c.category_id
GROUP BY m.movie_title
```

If you just want them to be displayed as separate rows:

```
SELECT m.movie_title,c.category_title
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN categories_movies cm 
 ON m.movie_id = cm.movie_id
INNER JOIN categories c
 ON cm.category_id = c.category_id
```

Comment: This is what I wanted, You understood me better than I asked, THANK YOU

Comment: Now how to display movies based on a category id or category_title?

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to use left join :

`SELECT m.movie_title,c.category_title
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN categories_movies cm 
 ON m.movie_id = cm.movie_id
LEFT JOIN categories c
 ON cm.category_id = c.category_id`

Comment: you can use group by statement in query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT movies.movie_title, GROUP_CONCAT(`category_title` SEPARATOR ',') as category 
FROM `categories_movies` 
left join categories on categories.category_id=categories_movies.category 
left join movies on movies.movie_id=categories_movies.movie_id 
GROUP BY categories_movies.movie_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT().It works perfectly:

```
 SELECT movies.movie_title, GROUP_CONCAT( categories.category_title ) 
    FROM movies 
    INNER JOIN categories_movies ON movies.movie_id = categories_movies.movie_id
    INNER JOIN categories ON categories_movies.category_id = categories.category_id
    GROUP BY movies.movie_title;
```

Comment: Isn't that a copy of my answer?

Comment: No that is not the copy.I tried the above code in mysql and then wrote here. I saw your answer after I post mine